# Wordpress Full Site Editing: How can I access my posts listing page?

Tags: block-editor, full-site-editing

In WordPress 6.0, I've created a block based theme using [fullsiteediting.com's theme generator](https://fullsiteediting.com/block-theme-generator/). It had a default homepage which listed posts. Within the block editor (sidebar->Templates->Add New button), I added a "Front Page" for the theme. Now that template is set as the homepage. So, how can I see the list of all posts in the website now? 
In WordPress Settings->Reading, it's still set to "Your latest posts" as the homepage. Is this some disconnect that the developers haven't cleared yet? Should I create a new page in Pages that will query all the posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it sounds like there might be some sort of disconnect, as the template editor doesn't make this clear, but keep in mind that FSE is still marked as being in Beta in the latest version of WordPress.

Templates in full site editing still follow the [standard template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/). So if you want a static homepage you should set one in *Settings > Reading*, as well as a page for your posts. With that done your *Front Page* block template will be used to render the front page, while the *Home* block template will be used for the posts page.